# Gridview rows unaccessible at server side

Tags: asp.net

I have used an `asp:GridView` with `ClientIDMode="Static"` and I`D="GridView2"` that shows some specific results let,s say accounts details on a button click.

First I was Databounding the grid and every thing was okay other than postback delay and whole page redraw.

```
(GridView2.DataSource = datatable.DefaultView;
 GridView2.DataBind();)
```

Now I am using Ajax to update this grid(I create the html of grid in Ajax function and overwrite it on Grid html like that

```
$('#GridView2').html(html.join(''))
```

),it is drawing properly but now I am unable to access its rows on server side.

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < mayDataGrid.Rows.Count; rows++)//.Rows.Count is always 0 but in html it is there.
```

Comment: you should wrap GridView in UpdatePanel to ajaxify the grid instead of manually injecting html in dom element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a gridview renders it also renders its ControlState in ViewState, when a page postbacks grid's current state (row changes like add/edit/delete etc.) detected on server by this ControlState and not by html markup (you are changing).

Thus any changes to the html will not take effect at serverside.